# How to find earliest restore point for database on Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

Azure SQL Database Managed Instance shows the earliest time when the database can be restored on Azure portal. Is there a way to find it programmatically  using PowerShell or Azure CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earliest restore date can be programmatically retrieved using [Get-AzureRmSqlInstanceDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/get-azurermsqlinstancedatabase?view=azurermps-6.13.0) PowerShell command using the following code:

```
Get-AzureRmSqlInstanceDatabase -InstanceName "jovanpop-test-instance" -ResourceGroupName "my_rg" |
Select-Object Name, CreationDate, EarliestRestorePoint

Name                       CreationDate           EarliestRestorePoint
----                       ------------           -------------------- 
ValidationDB               1/22/2019 11:00:42 AM  1/22/2019 11:02:35 AM
WideWorldImportersDWFull   7/4/2018 7:55:59 AM    1/15/2019 11:31:00 AM
tpcc1000                   8/27/2018 2:37:23 PM   1/15/2019 11:31:00 AM
WideWorldImportersStandard 7/4/2018 8:00:14 AM    1/15/2019 11:31:00 AM
```

If you are initiating point-in-time restore, these dates are the boundary values that you can use.